# save instagram high resolution images from instagram

Tags: php, json, instagram

I'm writing a desktop app requiring to download images from Instagram (primarily the ones that belong to the user authenticated in this app). When I try to query the images via the api (be it users/self/feed, or media/{id}) I can only see the links to 612px x 612px images inside the returned in JSON data. So the main question is:

Q1) Is it possible to save the image with the resolution higher than 612 x 612 using the API?

They claim (http://help.instagram.com/276722745781769/) that when the photos are taken from the instagram app the images uploaded to instagram site are stored with the resolution higher than that. So I took a few pictures with Instagram app installed on an iPhone 4 device and tried to access them from PC. Still API Console reveals only 612x612 (standard_resolution) image urls, and no higher. I also tried a few free desktop apps supposedly assisting in downloading images from the Instagram like Instagram Downloader 2.3.0.0 (Free), and some others, without being able to access > 612x612 resolutions.

So if the answer to Q1 is positive, I'd also like to know:

Q2) How can I get access to the higher resolution images via the API?

These questions are, imo, very natural, so I've a feeling like I've overlooked something obvious.

Comment: As Greg says, duplicating a question - regardless of whether you are the author of the original - is not ideal. (We are a Q&A site, not a forum, and try to offer a well-written set of questions that will be helpful to as many people as possible - duplicate questions detract from that goal). It is better to comment on the question and/or upvote (and perhaps ask a new question in your own words if that fails too!).

Comment: You can download any instagram photo in higher quality using `/media/?size=l` next to any instagram photo landing page address [like this](https://www.instagram.com/p/8caZr0M_7R/media/?size=l).

Comment: Any updation in this? Because still I am getting lower resolution images via API usage.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> High-resolution versions of your Instagram photos are saved to your device after you upload the photo to Instagram. This means that you are the only one with access to high-resolution versions of your photos.

No, you can't get high-resolution versions unless you have access to the device that took the picture.

Comment: I read this on their website though:  For Apple (iOS) devices, the resolutions of photos taken with the Instagram camera (not the Camera application) and saved to your device are:

    2048x2048 on the iPhone 4s and up
    1936x1936 on the iPhone 4
    1536x1536 on the iPhone 3GS

Please note that photos imported from your iOS device (not taken with the Instagram camera) and then uploaded to Instagram will save at a much lower resolution (612x612). Apple has recently updated their API to allow high resolution importing to applications, and while this feature will be available in the....

Comment: This question was never answered. This isn't a new account. I'm a different person with the same question.

Comment: ...the resolutions of photos taken with the Instagram camera (not the Camera application) `and saved to your device` are...

Comment: If you're a different person with the same question, upvote the question. Duplicates will be closed.

Comment: The question was asked a long time ago. I figured upvoting would not help.

Comment: So why aren't my photos 2048X2048? or higher than 612X612. I tried on two different accounts. We used instagram's camera.

Comment: The photos that are uploaded to instagram are 612x612. You cannot get any higher resolutions via their api. Never, ever, ever. You need to have physical access to the device to get a higher resolution image than 612x612. No matter what resolution they were saved as on the phone, you will still only be able to access 612x612 via the API. Period. Please re-read the documentation until you understand that.

Comment: Ok. I was reading this and it wasn't clear to me: http://help.instagram.com/276722745781769/